# Rails routes: different domains to different places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've got a Rails app up running on a server. It's a big project so there are lots of routes involved, and two domains point to the root at the moment. I'd like to somehow design my `routes.rb` to interpret one domain to take it to a certain part of the app as if it was the root, and use the other for everywhere else.

Something like this (very pseudocode, hope you get the idea):

```
whole_app.com
whole_app.com/documents
whole_app.com/share
whole_app.com/users
partial_app.com, :points_to => 'whole_app.com/share'
```

Can Rails handle this? Thank-you!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by overriding default url_options method in application controller. This will override host url for every request.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ....
  def default_url_options
    if some_condition
      {:host => "partial_app.com"}
    else  
      {:host => "whole_app.com"}
    end
  end
  ....
end
```

And for pointing a route to some specific url, you may use:

```
match "/my_url" => redirect("http://google.com/"), :as => :my_url_path
```

The better way is to do settings on server to redirect some url to a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

is it going to `/share` based on some kind of criteria?  if so you can do this:

`routes.rb`

```
root :to => 'pages#home'
```

`pages_controller.rb`

```
def home
  if (some condition is met) 
    redirect_to this_path
  else
    render :layout => 'that'
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, yeah, I could check the domain in the controller. This just seems like it could be better managed from `routes.rb`.